# update multiple data if exists, create if does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert or update multiple rows. if some data already exists then it will update otherwise it will create new items. My code from are :

```
foreach ($product_id as $key => $value) {
    $input['product_name'] = $request->product_name[$key];
    $input['product_price'] = $request->product_price[$key];

    $add_product = Product::upsert($input,'product_name');
}
```

I am not getting any error, Its just inserting all data instead of updating the existing items.

Comment: could you please mention what error you are getting in mentioned code

Comment: I am not getting any error, it's just inserting all data instead of updating existing items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `updateOrCreate` if product_name column is not primary key or unique key in database

```
foreach ($product_id as $key => $value) {
        $input['product_name'] = $request->product_name[$key];
        $input['product_price'] = $request->product_price[$key];
    
        $add_product = Product::updateOrCreate(['product_name'=>$request->product_name[$key]], $input);
}
```

if column product_name is unique or primary key then

```
$data=[]; 

    foreach ($product_id as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key]['product_name'] = $request->product_name[$key];
        $data[$key]['product_price'] = $request->product_price[$key]; 
    } 
    $add_product = Product::upsert($data,['product_name']);
```

As per doc

> All databases except SQL Server require the columns in the second
> argument of the upsert method to have a "primary" or "unique" index.
> In addition, the MySQL database driver ignores the second argument of
> the upsert method and always uses the "primary" and "unique" indexes
> of the table to detect existing records.

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `::firstOrCreate($data)` for this, it returns the item when found or the inserted item when there could not be an item found with the inserted data. You can find it here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

```php
foreach ($product_id as $key => $value) {
    $input['product_name'] = $request->product_name[$key];
    $input['product_price'] = $request->product_price[$key];

    $add_product = Product::firstOrCreate($input);
}
```

What I would do when you need to update multiple products instead of just one is checking the count of the product with the specific information. After this I would update it when the count is higher than 1.

```php
foreach ($product_id as $key => $value) {
    $input['product_name'] = $request->product_name[$key];
    $input['product_price'] = $request->product_price[$key];

    $productCount = Product::where('product_name', $request->product_name[$key])->count();

    if ($productCount > 1) {
      $products = Product::where('product_name', $request->product_name[$key])->get();
      $products->update($input);
    } else {
      $add_product = Product::firstOrCreate($input);
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I did not test the code.

Comment: I am getting this error `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::updatedoes not exist.
`